# Create a dataframe with all combinations of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following data example:

```
df1 <- tibble(V1 = c("a", "b", "c"), 
              V2 = c("b", "b", "f"), 
              v3 = c(1:3))
```

I would like to generate this output from the df1:

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   V1    V2       v3
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 a     b         1
 2 b     b         2
 3 c     f         3
 4 a     a         0
 5 a     c         0
 6 a     f         0
 7 b     a         0
 8 b     c         0
 9 b     f         0
10 c     a         0
11 c     b         0
12 c     c         0
13 f     a         0
14 f     b         0
15 f     c         0
16 f     f         0
```

I try it, but not works:

```
df1 %>% complete(V1, V2,
                 fill = list(V3 = 0))
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to add the levels - convert the columns 'V1', 'V2' to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` levels from both the columns, and then use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(df1[1:2])))
df1 %>% 
  complete(V1 = factor(V1, levels = lvls),
   V2 = factor(V2, levels = lvls), 
   fill = list(v3 = 0)) %>% 
   arrange(v3 == 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   V1    V2       v3
   <chr> <chr> <int>
 1 a     b         1
 2 b     b         2
 3 c     f         3
 4 a     a         0
 5 a     c         0
 6 a     f         0
 7 b     a         0
 8 b     c         0
 9 b     f         0
10 c     a         0
11 c     b         0
12 c     c         0
13 f     a         0
14 f     b         0
15 f     c         0
16 f     f         0
```

Comment: Why is `crossing()` not working here?

Comment: @TarJae You may need `invoke(crossing, df1)`, but that returns 18 rows because 'v3' is also used

Answer (score 1):

tidyr::expand() solves this. It can be used for multiple column combinations

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve your problem using data.table:

```
library(data.table)

cases = unique(c(df1$V1, df1$V2))

CJ(V1=cases, V2=cases, V3=0)[setDT(df1), V3 := i.v3, on=.(V1, V2)][order(V3==0)]

        V1     V2    V3
 1:      a      b     1
 2:      b      b     2
 3:      c      f     3
 4:      a      a     0
 5:      a      c     0
 6:      a      f     0
 7:      b      a     0
 8:      b      c     0
 9:      b      f     0
10:      c      a     0
11:      c      b     0
12:      c      c     0
13:      f      a     0
14:      f      b     0
15:      f      c     0
16:      f      f     0
```